# HeartBleed Openssl update Redhat Enterprise server 6.3

Tags: redhat, heartbleed

I already update using yum update openssl but still my server is vulnerable.
Tried `grep 'libssl.*(deleted)' /proc/*/maps` and no result as I already restarted the server.
Yet, it is still vulnerable.

```
$ rpm -qa | grep openssl
openssl-devel-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64
openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64
```

Did I miss something to execute?

I scanned my site with the  [acunetix scanner](http://ssllabs.com/ssltest),  and the one from redhat website. all says it is vulnerable.

Here are some additional details:

```
grep libssl.so.1.0.1e /proc/*/maps | cut -d/ -f3 | sort -u | xargs -r -- ps uf
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root     30932  0.0  0.3  77076  7612 ?        Ss   18:50   0:00 squid -f /etc/squid/squid.conf
squid    30935  0.0  1.3 119244 26256 ?        S    18:50   0:00  \_ (squid-1) -f /etc/squid/squid.conf
root     30907  0.0  0.2  81328  3852 ?        Ss   18:50   0:00 /usr/libexec/postfix/master
postfix  30911  0.0  0.2  81592  3872 ?        S    18:50   0:00  \_ qmgr -l -t fifo -u
postfix  31221  0.0  0.1  81408  3840 ?        S    20:30   0:00  \_ pickup -l -t fifo -u
root     30775  0.0  1.0 290340 20900 ?        Ss   18:50   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   31041  0.0  1.6 520736 31100 ?        Sl   19:08   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   31042  0.0  1.1 316740 22496 ?        Sl   19:08   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   31043  0.0  0.9 313992 18868 ?        Sl   19:08   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   31044  0.0  1.4 520416 28544 ?        Sl   19:08   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   31047  0.0  1.0 314700 21104 ?        Sl   19:08   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   31048  0.0  1.4 448284 27656 ?        Sl   19:08   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   31051  0.0  1.2 317584 23292 ?        Sl   19:08   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   31052  0.0  1.1 317472 22872 ?        Sl   19:08   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   31065  0.0  1.1 316592 21676 ?        Sl   19:09   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   31082  0.0  1.4 445272 28168 ?        Sl   19:30   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   31085  0.0  0.8 313452 17208 ?        Sl   19:30   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   31086  0.0  1.0 315984 20944 ?        Sl   19:30   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   31091  0.0  1.4 447032 27504 ?        Sl   19:31   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   31094  0.0  0.8 311240 16208 ?        Sl   19:31   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   31095  0.0  1.1 316264 21408 ?        Sl   19:31   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   31210  0.0  0.8 311228 16100 ?        Sl   20:23   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd


 ldd sbin/httpd
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff50dff000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd9501e5000)
        libpcre.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre.so.0 (0x00007fd94ffb9000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fd94fd99000)
        libaprutil-1.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libaprutil-1.so.0 (0x00007fd94fb75000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fd94f93e000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fd94f715000)
        libdb-4.7.so => /lib64/libdb-4.7.so (0x00007fd94f3a1000)
        libapr-1.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00007fd94f175000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd94ef57000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd94ebc3000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd94e9bf000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003747a00000)
        libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fd94e7ba000)
        libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007fd94e541000)

openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
built on: Thu Oct 16 11:05:49 EDT 2014
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DKRB5_MIT -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -Wall -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wa,--noexecstack -DPURIFY -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
engines:  dynamic
```

Comment: What tool are you using to check the server is vulnerable?

Comment: What gets targeted by the scanner? Is it possible you scan something which brings it's own SSL library instead of using the one provided by the OS?

Comment: Thank you for editing. above are my details. i haven't re-compile my openssl and delete the old library ( this is what i saw in other forums )

Answer (score 5):

OpenSSL on RHEL6 is affected only in versions `openssl-1.0.1e-15` through `openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4`. `openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7` and later contain a fix backported from OpenSSL 1.0.1g and don't bump the letter part of the serial number up. Thus, it's likely you are confused by the `e` and your system is in fact patched.

Source: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/781793

BTW: You are *very* late for that particular party.

Comment: Hi Sven, thank you for your reply ,yes i patched it with current openssl update , but scanning tools says it is still vulnerable to heartbleed. This is only the only server i have which is still vulnerable, all the rest are patched via "yum update openssl " and was no longer affected after scan.  i dont know what else to do, i did a restart and perform grep 'libssl.*(deleted)' /proc/*/maps and no package is using the old ones anymore. yet still vulnerable.